# I configure Rails-React with webpack, but still render JSON of index in browser instead of React-Hello

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, webpack

I created a rails app with `webpack=react`. I create my model `Post` with attributes as usual, and at the controller I render JSON of all.

**posts_controller.erb**

```rb
def index 
  @posts = Post.all          

  render json: { data: @posts }
end
```

Then, I add the JS pack `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>` to the application.html.erb file, like this:

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RailsReactPokedex</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My routes file to the index:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "posts#index"
end
```

And when I start the server, the browser renders the JSON, instead of the 'Hello-React' message.

Any ideas what could be failing?

Comment: You added a javascript tag to your base HTML template, but in your controller you are responding with JSON not HTML. Since you aren't responding with HTML, no HTML is sent to the browser and thus its Javascript isn't either.

Comment: Unfortunately, thatś not the problem. I change it to render to html and it renders the active record objects. I've seen tutorials setting it to render to json and when they add '<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>' to the index view or application.html, the hello-react message shows. But to me only renders the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have added gem `react-rails` in the gemfile.

And seems like you only have created an API to render `JSON` data.
You will also  need a static HTML to start your react App.
I suggest you create two different routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # API routes
  namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'
  end
  # Empty static controller to render our react App
  root 'static#index'
end
```

Then create a react component
`rails generate react:component HelloWorld greeting:string`

which should look like

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render () {
   return (
     <React.Fragment>
       Greeting: {this.props.greeting}
     </React.Fragment>
   );
  }
}
HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string
};
export default HelloWorld
```

Then in your views `app/views/static/index.html.erb` file

```
<%= react_component('HelloWorld', {greeting: 'Hello'}) %>
```

Now visit your browser to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks man!! The API routing was failing! I jsut posted the answer. Big thanks! It was driving me crazy

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You are right! I was missing the API routes. For some reason React doesn' t read JSON directly. I fixed it with this:

```
#routes.rb
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'posts/index'
    end
end
  
  root 'posts#index'
```

And then created a posts_controller for that API:

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: {posts: @posts }
  end

end
```

And that fixed it.